# How to Get Height, Width , X and Y of UIImageView on Button click and pass it to Other ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm creating an iOS app(objective c) and in this app I'm setting `UIImageview`(movable) on `UIView`(like Sticker). What I want to do next is when User click on button that time a new `ViewController` will open and that time `UIImageview` should be on same position(same height & width) like it's last position, height and width on previous `ViewController`. But I don't know how to save position of `UIImageview` and use it on other `ViewController`. I know how to use properties from other `ViewController` but not getting any idea of this specific one.

Comment: can you share some code that you trying?

Comment: is your `UIImageview` in some view or directly in main view? show the hierarchy for your `UIImageview`.

Comment: @RonakChaniyara I've created UIImageView programmatically. Its in UIView not in direct main view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in button action method:

```
// Convert the co-ordinates of the view into the window co-ordinate space

   CGRect frame = [yourImgView.superview convertRect:yourImgView.frame toView:self.view];
```

Now, `frame` will be your `UIImageview` frame in your full viewController view, which you can pass to next viewController and use there.

Comment: Hey!! Thank you for quick response!! Could you please tell me how to access this `CGRect` in other ViewController? Because I can't access this as I access string or image or arrays.

Comment: take frame as property in second vc and pass when push that vc from first vc.

Comment: HTH@MaulikDesai

Answer (score 0):

I Think You just need to pass the Frame of the image view before you create the new controller as property in the controller to set new the image view with that frame.

ViewController1 :

```
let imageViewFrame = yourimageView.frame
```

Viewcontroller2 :

```
var imageFrame : CGRect?

Viewcontroller2.imageFrame =  imageViewFrame

newImageView.frame = imageFrame
```